# How can I display php in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have some code and basically I want to display it in php. Here is the code:

```
   <script>
   var useridisplay = GetQueryStringParams('user_id');  
   </script>
```

Basically the code I want to grab to display in php is the useridisplay so I would want to do something like this code:

```
   <script>
   var useridisplay = GetQueryStringParams('user_id');  
   var useridisplay = <? $useridisplay; ?>; 
   </script>
```

So bascially I want to display my code in php here is the code:

```
   <? echo $useridisplay; ?>
```

How can I display my code?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Usually it's not a common design because php is running on the server side while js is running on your browser. The right way to call a js variable in php is to use form submit or ajax.

Comment: you cannot use the similar way as you call a PHP variable in javascript. you have to submit a form with the parameter from the javascript to the PHP. See [PHP Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a simple PHP variable available in Javascript like this:

```
var useridisplay = "<?php echo $useridisplay; ?>";
```

Just note that inside your PHP it has the `echo` statement, and *outside* the PHP code it has quotes surrounding it.

Note also that you want to sanitize that PHP variable first before just spitting it out, so someone can't inject arbitrary code into your page. In addition to sanitizing server side, it's good practice to use `json_encode` when echoing to a javascript variable:

```
var useridisplay = <?php echo json_encode($useridisplay); ?>;
```

Comment: This is dangerous, use `json_encode` and check for `</script>` if appropriate.

Comment: @minitech Well clearly you want to sanitize your variables. He's not spitting out a `$_GET` variable directly, or else I would have mentioned that. I updated anyway to make note.

Comment: `json_encode` means you can take off the quotes, too. And escape-on-output is generally a “fewer unpleasant surprises” way of doing things than sanitize-on-input.